# Where is DateTickUnit documentation?

Tags: jfreechart, timeserieschart

I need to change the default DateTickUnit settings for different zoom levels for a TimeseriesChart, but can´t find the place i need to read in the documentation? I would greatly appreciate a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Java API for TimeSeriesChartDemo1: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html

The zoom levels documentation will be found in one of the inherited methods. I would recommend finding the exact component that requires the zoom to be changed on. Then checking the API for that java.awt component

Comment: Actually, it's [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) that illustrates `setStandardTickUnit()`, as shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.64).

Answer (score 2):

[`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) has two static factories for creating standard date tick units. These methods, `createStandardDateTickUnits()`, describe how "to create your own collection." The `setTickUnit()` methods replace the default with your own [`DateTickUnit`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateTickUnit.html). The constructor having a `DateFormat` is particularly convenient.

If this is *terra incognita*, I'd recommend [*The JFreeChart Developer Guide*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; just a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>

Comment: I got the guide, will spend some grey matter on it. Long read, though :)

Comment: Excellent; IIRC, there's an example under `org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnit`. I'm surprised you have to change the units for zoom; you may be able to change just the format.