# Time Series JFreeChart repaint the time axis

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I created a dynamic time series chart using JFreeChart API. and it is working fine. I have to add a combo box to it, in which time values will be there like 5 sec, 15 sec, 30 sec. when user choose on from it the time axis has to repaint with given interval and the timer has to delay the process for 5, 15,30 seconds(updating the chart). I this on my previous post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188219/jfreechart-timeseries-is-not-refreshing)

with some extensions like adding combo box to it

but it's not worked for me, any help will be appreciated. thanks

**EDIT 1** removed unwanted code and remaining code is

```
    final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =
    new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 60, new Second());

dataset.setTimeBase(new Second( 0,seriesvalue*2, 5, 11, 7, 2012));

dataset.addSeries(new float[]{0}, 0, "Currency Rate");
JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);


final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
combo.addItem("5");
combo.addItem("15");
combo.addItem("30");

combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if("5".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())){
      seriesvalue=5;
      timer.setDelay(seriesvalue*1000);
    }else  if("15".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())){

      seriesvalue=15;
      timer.setDelay(seriesvalue*1024);
      unit=new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MINUTE,seriesvalue);
      chartPanel.repaint();
    }
  }
});
    add(chartPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(combo,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
timer = new Timer(999*seriesvalue, new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          for(int i=0;i<seriesvalue;i++){

            newData[0] = randy.getRandomvalue();
            dataset.advanceTime();
            dataset.appendData(newData);

          }             

        }
    });
```

create dataset code

```
  private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
   JFreeChart result= ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
      "Dyanmic chart", "hh:mm:ss", "Currency", dataset, true, true, false);
  final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();

  dateAxis= (DateAxis)plot.getDomainAxis();
  unit = new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MINUTE,seriesvalue/2);
  return result;
}
```

main method

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          DynaChart chart = new DynaChart();
          chart.pack();
          RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(chart);
          chart.setVisible(true);
          chart.start();
      }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Are you using `TimeSeriesCollection ` or `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach.

Comment: I am using DynamicTimeSeriesCollection

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your requirement from the fragments you've posted. If you just need to sample the data source at a few different frequencies, you can set the `javax.swing.Timer` delay as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513).

Addendum: *I want to repaint the `DateAxis`*.

The API notes that [`setTimeBase()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.html#setTimeBase%28org.jfree.data.time.RegularTimePeriod%29) "Will silently return if the time array was already populated." I suspect that you will need to recreate the `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` in your combo's action listener. You may also want to alter the tick units and format of the `DateAxis`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350282/230513).

Comment: i am setting delay in the above code in combo box action event. but i want to repaint the dateaxis. eg if i choose 15 seconds the time axis has to display 7 min interval on the line. and if i choose 5sec it has to show 2 min interval on time line. so i assigned **unit** combo box code and repaint the chartpanel. it didn't work for me.

Comment: I've elaborated above; don't hesitate to edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.